# How can we prove that $-i = \frac{1}{i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Probably avery basic question but it seems that for the imaginary number $i^2 = -1$
$$
-i = \frac{1}{i}
$$
how can we prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of the number $i$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. thanks for the comment. $i = \sqrt{-1}$. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: This is a horrible definition, you should never use square roots for negative real numbers !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: I reedited the definition. Is less hurtful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the laws of algebra as you would in verifying any equation:
\begin{align*}
-i = \frac{1}{i} & \iff (-i) \cdot i = 1 \\
  & \iff - i^2 = 1 \\
  & \iff -(-1) = 1 \qquad\qquad\text{(using that $i^2=-1$)}\\
  & \iff 1 = 1
\end{align*}
which is true.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{i}{i}=\frac{i}{i^2}=\frac{i}{-1}=-i$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$-x=\frac1x$$ is solved by

$$x^2=-1$$ isn't it ?